# Need value from input tag and use in pyramid program

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make small form in which I have taken input box in which user enter integer value to draw rows for pyramid program and drop box to select the program to display...But now I want to take the value from input box that will be given to pyramid program as input to draw the program...

```
     <html>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="form2.html">
No. of Rows<input type="number" name="Rows" id="rvalue"><br>
TYPE:<select name="Make your choice">
<option value="Triangle">Triangle</option>
<option value="Pyramid">Pyramid</option>
</select><br>
<a href="javascript:submitform()">Submit</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(){
   if(document.getElementById("rvalue").value==number)
   {
      document.forms["myform"].submit();
  }
else
  {
     window.alert("Please enter integer value")
   }
}
function prog1(){
rows=document.getElementById("rvalue").value;
 for(i=1;i<=rows;++i)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        {
           document.write("* ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }

function prog2(){
rows=document.getElementById("rvalue").value;
for(i=1;i<=rows;++i)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=rows-i;++j)
        {
           printf("  ");
        }
        while(k!=2*i-1)
        {
           document.write("* ");
           ++k;
        }
        k=0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('rvalue').value` ?

Comment: How I will make aan event trigger on drop down?

Comment: `<select name="Make your choice" onchange='YourFunction()'>` or give `id` to select element and use `addEventListener`..

Comment: hey I am new in javscript please help me..

Comment: I want if user select triangle from drop down the code associated with it execute and vice versa

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u4yrhcwq/

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre-tx for ur help..But can you explain me ur onChoiceChange function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104948/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-rupali-rana).